# zeppelin spark.pyspark interpreter error: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute '_wrapped'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

when using %spark.pyspark interpreter, got the error:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to bootstrap pyspark
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:844)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:752)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(FIFOScheduler.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to bootstrap pyspark
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:105)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to run bootstrap script: python/zeppelin_pyspark.py
Fail to execute line 54:   sqlc = __zSqlc__ = __zSpark__._wrapped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1680782064460_0001/container_1680782064460_0001_01_000001/tmp/python16531023262914108461/zeppelin_python.py", line 162, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 54, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute '_wrapped'

    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.bootstrapInterpreter(PythonInterpreter.java:579)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:102)
    ... 9 more
```

zeppelin version: 0.10.1

spark version: 3.3.0

Tested ipython, pyspark outside zeppelin, worked fine.

Comment: Looks like this has a JIRA issue in the Zeppelin project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5928